# How to pass a state variable into a function in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, state

It is widely known that it is possible to declare state variables in react js files and have those state variables appear in the render() function.

However, I am faced with an application in which I have to get the value of certain state variables and pass their values into an object called "data" (see code below) that feeds into a component that makes tables (like bar charts, graphs, etc.). I am attempting to use a GET request from HTTP to get the values of the state variables, which works fine (I hope), but the state variables simply won't go into the data array `data: []`. I would appreciate some help. Further code is down below.

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      teacher_name: '',
      confusion: 0,
      surprised: 0,
      happy: 0,
      sad: 0,
}

componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('http://localhost:8000/api/school/frames/' + localStorage.getItem('first_name') + '_' + localStorage.getItem('last_name'))
    .then(response =>
    {
      
      this.setState({teacher_name: response.teacher_name, confusion: response.confusion, surprised: response.surprised, happy: 100, sad: response.sad})
      console.log(response)
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error)
    })
  }

  data = {
    labels: ["Happy", "Sad", "Surprised", "Confused"],
    datasets: [this.state.happy(), {
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: [**ATTEMPTING TO PUT STATE VARIABLES HERE**],
      backgroundColor: [
        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
      ],
      borderColor: [
        'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
      ],
      borderWidth: 1,
      fill: false
    }]
};
```

Comment: What state values are you trying to store in the data array? Also is there any reason why you are not using your data object as a state value? If you define your data object in state you can later pass this state object over as prop to your component that needs this information

Answer (score 0):

```
data =[{this.state.yourState}]
```

**or**

```
var myData = this.state.yourState

data = {
    labels: ["Happy", "Sad", "Surprised", "Confused"],
    datasets: [this.state.happy(), {
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: [{myData}],

...
}
```

**or**

```
var myData = this.state.yourState

data = {
    labels: ["Happy", "Sad", "Surprised", "Confused"],
    datasets: [this.state.happy(), {
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: [myData],

...
}
```